# SSRS 2008 Dataset

Tags: sql-server, web-services, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report with two Datasets. One is a Dataset from a Database SQL Query, resulting to one or more rows.

The other one is an  XML Dataset that consumes a Web Service. Query for the dataset is shown below.

```
<Query>
<SoapAction>http://tempuri.org/CCT_Route_WS/FindCCTRoute/FindBasicNumber</SoapAction>
<Method Namespace="http://tempuri.org/" Name="FindBasicNumber"></Method>
</Query>
```

I need to pass a parameter (named *CCTNumber*) which is a column from the first (SQL) Dataset. How can I do that? I have seen that I can pass a parameter in the 2nd Dataset named "QueryOptions", but I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance for your prompt reply.

Regards,

Marios Tofarides

Comment: Add the parameter in report set it's values to the your first datasets column which have values and then pass that parameter to the xml request.

Comment: I did try to do that (add parameters in 2nd dataset), but when I run the report, I get the following Error: "The expression used for the parameter 'Circuit Number' in the dataset 'CircuitNumber' refers to a field. Fields cannot be used in query parameter expressions"

Comment: How did you set the parameter value ?

Comment: From Dataset Properties --> Parameters

Comment: Do you need anything else? A screenshot maybe?

Comment: THat would be great. Add it I don't have time right now. SO when I will get free first thing I will do to look up that.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post any images. My reputation is low. The first Dataset, as I mentioned, get more than one rows. CCTNumber parameter is selected from the 1st Dataset. The problem is CCTNumber parameter gets the same value for every row; the value of the first row. I need a different value for each row to be passed to the 2nd Dataset as Parameters

Comment: To make it clearer: Let's say the 1st Dataset has 3 rows. Values for CCT Number are 22334455 (Row 1), 31123456 (Row 2) and 3023456 (Row 3). As I sais, parameter CCTNumber gets its values from Dataset1. Now, when I show the parameter on the report, it gets only value 22334455 on all rows. I wish I could send the .rdl file for you to see. Thanks for the help